# JQuery: How can I extend a script over some dynamically loaded content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I have a little problem that I was hoping some of you could help me out with.

On clicking a button, I would like to update a div with the content of another page.

Let's say that homepage.html is like this:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JQUERY.JS"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function()
   {
    $(".alert").click(function()
    {
     alert("HELLO");
     return false;
    });

    $(".load").click(function()
    {
     $("#content").load("FILE.HTML");
     return false;
    });
   });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <a href="#" class="load">CLICK ME</a>
  <div id="content"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

A rather simple file.

Now let's say that FILE.HTML has this line only:

```
      <a href="#" class="alert">CLICK ME</a>
```

Now what I am looking for is: when i click .alert, the alert box pops up. I don't know why it doesn't.

**So my question is**: why is my loaded code not affected by the script?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [jQuery Delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to achieve that...

Answer (score 0):

The contents from `file.html` are not present the moment you attach the click event to the `".alert"` items (actually there are no `.alert` items when that code runs!).

You need to use jQuery's [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) methods which use **event bubbling** in order to capture events not only from existing elements but also from new elements that are inserted in the DOM later.

This also has the nice side effect of using only one event handler instead of one for each `.alert` element.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use [`$.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
$(".alert").live('click', function()
  {
    alert("HELLO");
    return false;
  });
```

You don't have to wait until you add in your dynamic content, this function applies your event handler to all future elements that match your selector.